# Error and Warning Handling in Python

Tags: python, bash, popen

I'm trying to make a script that handles errors and warnings from other scripts, it can be other python or bash scripts.

The only way I found to do this is by using Popen, I execute the script using Popen and store the stderr into a variable.

Checking the returncode of Popen I can say if the stderr is a warning (returncode 0, the script ran successfully) or if it is in fact an error (returncode 1, the script did not run successfully).

But there are some scripts that even with error they continue the commands and so the returncode is 0 like it was some warning or the script did run successfully. How can I handle this sort of thing?

Here are some samples to get a full understanding:

```
sshpass -p password sftp -q username@host << EOF
cd Export
get file.csv
EOF
```

This bash script gives me an error that it cannot find the file.csv, ok.

```
File "/Export/file.csv" not found.
```

This python script executes the script above.

```
script = 'bash_script'
proc = subprocess.Popen("bash {}.sh ".format(script), stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if (proc.returncode) and (stderr != ''):
      print("\n[ERROR]:\n" + str(stderr))
elif (not proc.returncode) and (stderr != ''):
      print("\n[WARNING]:\n" + str(stderr))
else # (not proc.returncode) and (stderr == '')
      print("\n[SUCCESS]\n")
```

But executing the script above I get:

```
[WARNING]:
File "/Export/file.csv" not found
```

When it should be:

```
[ERROR]:
File "/Export/file.csv" not found
```

This happens because the returncode is 0 and the error went to stderr as expected.

How can I handle this case? What is the best way to diferentiate errors from warnings? Why the sftp command is returning 0 when it should be returning 1 which corresponds to an error?

Comment: Why are you using command-line `ssh`? Use Python SSH library.

Comment: This is just an example of a bash script that is giving me an unexpected returncode. My script has the objective to run pyhton and bash scripts. I can use Python SSH in new scripts, but I can't change every single script on the server to use Python, understand?

Comment: Good, so then I'm removing the [tag:sftp] tag, as your question is not about SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this entirely from python, I suggest you implement logging in the bash scripts. In python, you can simply read the error from the logs like:

```
fault = ""
error = ""
warning = ""
with open('log.txt','r') as f:
    x = f.readline()
    if 'error' in x.lower():
       fault = "error"
       error = x
       print("The type is {} and it says:\n {}".format(fault,error))
    elif 'warning' in x.lower():
       fault = "warning"
       warning = x
       print("The type is {} and it says:\n {}".format(fault,warning))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to implement logging through bash as you suggested and see if it does the job.

Comment: @MarcusVinícius Alright lemme know if you face any errors